# With Doxygen output chmcmd produces fake error messages

Tags: html, doxygen, chm

I am creating a .chm documentation, from Doxygen files, using chmcmd.
The latter presents me with (fake) error messages, like

> Error: Anchor [HTML page, generated from a file containing @page]#[a @section or @subsection with label, all in the same file] undefined; first use [HTML page, generated from a file containing @page]

In the HTML file, I see lines

```
<li><a class="el" href="User_Guide.html#USER_GUIDE_SETUP_AND_DATA_FLOWS">SETUP AND DATA FLOWS</a><ol type="a">
```

and

```
<h1><a class="anchor" id="USER_GUIDE_SETUP_AND_DATA_FLOWS"></a>
SETUP AND DATA FLOWS</h1>
```

which, in my opinion, should be OK. The error message is fake, because
both the .html files and .chm file work OK. It seems to be harmless, but produces considerable noise, and I am afraid, I will miss some real errors.

Can I do something against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a chmcmd error. "@page" or "@section" have no meaning to chmcmd. Chmcmd generated no help, it just compiles, so from that viewpoint the message is not logical either.

Just in case, I grepped the source to be sure, and no hits.

So probably it is not chmcmd, but probably the error comes from the doxygen html-for-chm output module.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters make problems with the HTML Help compiler (see the attached links). I know this isn't the problem you described. I don't use `ChmCmd` so I unfortunately cannot reproduce your error message.

But, following thread from Help & manual Forums seems to give some information [Linking to anchors in chm topics from C#](https://helpman.it-authoring.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=12566). Please search for:

> Follow-up by Tim Green: Note that if the topic in question is the first topic in the CHM that's a known bug in the CHM system and unavoidable. It just doesn't synchronize with the topic if its on its own and not in a chapter. That's always been an issue in CHM and Microsoft has never corrected it. The synchronization of the TOC with the topics in CHM is also beyond Help & Manual's control; it's entirely controlled by Microsoft's viewer.

So, I think **"... first use ..."** in your error message is related to the issue meant in this thread.

Some further information from our HelpwareGroup site at:

[CHM Compiler crashed during compilation](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/hh-faq#TOC-Compilation-fails-abruptly----FAR-reports-MS-Compiler-hha.dll-has-crashed-during-compilation-)

[HTMLHelp CHM Frequently Asked Questions](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/hh-faq)

BTW, C# developers may discover that their documentation and e-books in CHM format cannot be opened because they store their CHM files in directories such as 'C:\E-books\C#\'. The hash character signifies an anchor in HTML so the CHM viewer fails to resolve the path properly and to retrieve the content. To resolve, remove the '#' (hash) character from the directory name. Also avoid using '?', '&', and '+' characters in directory names.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am documenting c++, and I use Doxygen output, without editing. In the lines I show in my post, the two lines seem to be perfect in my eyes. According to the follow-up, it looks like chmcmd too perfectly implements chm system :).

Comment: @katang Yes, the HTML anchor links are clean and OK for CHM too.